# Out of Memory Exception CreateBitmap

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I'm currently developing my first android application, which involves the user being able to acquire weapons in their inventory.  The weapons are randomly pieced together (hilt + blade + grip..etc) from drawables.  The inventory is a gridview with a custom ArrayAdapter to display the weapon icons.

The problem is I get an OutOfMemoryException once around 15 Weapons are generated.  My goal is for Inventory to be able to support hundreds of items.  From the logs, I was able to see that the problem lies here:
`Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(woh300, woh300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` The reason I make the bitmap so large is because I let the user be able to click on the weapon icons in the inventory, which brings up an enlarged image of them.

Here is the log for it:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1930512 byte allocation with 434524 free bytes and 424KB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:575)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:605)
            at com.example.android.justdoit.Weapon.<init>(Weapon.java:31)
            at com.example.android.justdoit.UpdateInvTask.onPostExecute(UpdateInvTask.java:48)
            at com.example.android.justdoit.UpdateInvTask.onPostExecute(UpdateInvTask.java:17)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

My Weapon class:

```
public class Weapon extends Equipment{
    public Weapon(Context context){
        //get the array of drawables located in the res/values/weapons.xml
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        TypedArray handles = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.handles);
        TypedArray hilts = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.hilts);
        TypedArray blades = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.blades);
        TypedArray middles = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.middles);
        TypedArray ends = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.ends);
        //randomize the grip, hilt, blade
        Random rand = new Random();
        Bitmap handle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), handles.getResourceId(rand.nextInt(handles.length()), 0));
        Bitmap hilt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), hilts.getResourceId(rand.nextInt(hilts.length()), 0));
        Bitmap blade = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), blades.getResourceId(rand.nextInt(blades.length()), 0));
        Bitmap end = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), ends.getResourceId(rand.nextInt(ends.length()), 0));
        Bitmap middle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), middles.getResourceId(rand.nextInt(middles.length()), 0));

        Bitmap[] parts = new Bitmap[5];
        parts[0] = handle;
        parts[1] = hilt;
        parts[2] = blade;
        parts[3] = middle;
        parts[4] = end;

        int woh5 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh25 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh130 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 130, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh138= Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 138, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh162 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 162, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh170 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 170, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh172 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 172, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh258 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 258, res.getDisplayMetrics()));
        int woh300 = Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300, res.getDisplayMetrics()));

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(woh300, woh300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        //rect is left, top, right, bottom
        //set the full image.  icon is a scaled-down version of the full image
        canvas.drawBitmap(parts[2], null, new Rect(woh5 * 25, woh5 * 6, woh5 * 35, woh5 * 37), paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(parts[0], null, new Rect(woh138, woh5 * 37, woh162, woh5 * 52), paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(parts[1], null, new Rect(woh25*3, woh172, woh25*9, woh5 * 42), paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(parts[3], null, new Rect(woh130, woh172, woh170, woh5 * 42), paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(parts[4], null, new Rect(woh138, woh258, woh162, woh5 * 57), paint);
        setFullImage(result);

        //recycle the typedarrays
        result = null;
        canvas = null;
        handles.recycle();
        hilts.recycle();
        blades.recycle();
        middles.recycle();
        ends.recycle();
    }
}
```

I've been reading the "Managing Bitmap Memory" section of the Android Developers Guide, but being my first application I know my bitmap creation is probably way off and I figured I could use some input if I need to completely change the way I generate bitmaps before trying to manage memory better.  Thank you.

Comment: Try to resize your bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

> Images come in all shapes and sizes. In many cases they are larger
>   than required for a typical application user interface (UI). For
>   example, the system Gallery application displays photos taken using
>   your Android devices's camera which are typically much higher
>   resolution than the screen density of your device.
>
> Given that you are working with limited memory, ideally you only want
>   to load a lower resolution version in memory. The lower resolution
>   version should match the size of the UI component that displays it. An
>   image with a higher resolution does not provide any visible benefit,
>   but still takes up precious memory and incurs additional performance
>   overhead due to additional on the fly scaling.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Each component that makes up a weapon is a png around 100-400 pixels by 100-400 pixels.  So I guess that makes the combined parts to be quite large.  But I ideally wanted to be able to have hundreds of weapons in the inventory so resizing the drawables still seems like not enough?

Comment: @user2562568 you can use a `GridView` to show your weapons. `GridView` implemented lazy loading.